# How do you change the foreground color of the VS Package Manager Console with PowerShell?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013

Using PowerShell, how do I change the foreground font color in the Visual Studio Package Manager Console?

When an error occurs, the foreground color turns white, and the background turns red, so it seems possible to modify the color.

I want to modify the color to highlight a certain status of my return results, so I need to be able to programmatically change the color with PowerShell.

After I change the color and use it, I want to return the color to the default. (much like the existing error formatting works)

Comment: the foreground colour is set by the host, i suggest you inspect your `$host` variable and look for a property that sets the foreground colour. In ISE for example its `$host.privatedata.ConsolepaneForegroundColor`

Comment: In my misunderstanding, I feel that I misled you all with the wording on this question. I don't want to change the foreground color permanently, just for a line or two. I found that Write-Host 'foo' -ForegroundColor Green works just fine in VS.

Answer (score 7):

Certain colors are customizable, but you can't use the standard `$host` properties. To customize VS powershell text colors, you can you **Tools->Options->Environment->Font and Colors** and modify the `Plain Text` option `Item foreground`. See example below...

However, there doesn't seem to be options anywhere to control the error/warning/debug/verbose/progress colors specifically [as is typically supported with other powershell consoles](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b43f071-abf5-4a65-9048-82d474473a8e/how-can-i-set-the-powershell-console-background-color-not-the-text-background-color?forum=winserverpowershell).

#### Modify Powershell Management Console in Visual Studio

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The properties that you would use in the standard console (`$host.PrivateData.ErrorForeGroundColor and $host.PrivateData.ErrorBackGroundColor`) are not available in the package manager console.